# Receiving java.sql.SQLException: out of memory

Tags: java, memory, netbeans

I got this error message in NetBeans 6.8:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: out of memory
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
        at org.sqlite.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:77)
        at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:88)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
```

I changed my VM options but am still receiving the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would help to know your host platform, sqlite version, and JDBC driver details.

Comment: Is this in the Database Connection Manager in Netbeans *or* is this in a program you wrote in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

Without any code snippet it's hard to give a decent answer.
After i googled this exception, it seems that many people faced this problem.
Try to remove the drive name (if any) from the JDBC URL this may help.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure, you are using correct URL for the database file.

Comment: That can cause 'out of memory' exceptions?